# Why does yubikey-personalization claim the zeroth USB interface?

Tags: yubico

I'm looking at the [`_ykusb_write()`](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-personalization/blob/master/ykcore/ykcore_libusb.c#L63) function from the [Yubikey-Personalization package](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-personalization/) and the first line of code executed is

```
int rc = usb_claim_interface((usb_dev_handle *)dev, 0);
```

Why is the zeroth USB interface claimed? From what I can tell from the `lsusb` output (see below) that interface is an HID and not the smartcard itself. I would had expected the 2nd interface to be claimed instead, but I do not understand this part of Yubikey very well. Where is it documented? Thank you for your help.

```
bNumInterfaces          3
Interface Descriptor:
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
  bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
  iInterface              0 
Interface Descriptor:
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
Interface Descriptor:
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bInterfaceClass        11 Chip/SmartCard
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  ChipCard Interface Descriptor:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YubiKey Personalization package referenced dates back to the YubiKey 1/2 models, which did not have CCID/Smart card support. The YubiKey 1/2 devices could only be communicated to via the HID keyboard interface, and identified to host devices as a USB keyboard. As such, the package attempts to connect to a YubiKey as if it was a keyboard.

The YubiKey Personalization package does not communicate over CCID/Smart card, but instead uses the HID keyboard interface. Yubico maintains this project as modern devices which support the touch-triggered OTP functions also can be programmed over the HID keyboard interface, and as such it remains useful for specific cases.